# Resize options on Ubuntu server virtualbox grayed out

Tags: server, virtualbox

Running Ubuntu server guest on Windows 7. Guest additions are installed properly to the best of my knowledge. But the resizing options are greyed out. The screen stays the same size in full screen and scaled option and "adjust window size" stays the same.

Whats am I doing wrong? How do I fixit?
Let me know if you need any specific information.

[image: greyed out]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't bother installing Guest Additions, it won't help you resize the terminal. Instead SSH into your Ubuntu VM using a program like [PuTTY](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html). You can customize and resize a PuTTY terminal very easily. Using an SSH Client also helps you avoid bloating your server with unnecessary software.

Answer (score 6):

In a server guest you likely have no XServer running. Virtualbox Guest Additions will load a virtual graphics drive to e.g. enable resizing the screen. However this driver depends on a running XServer and hence will be of no use in Ubuntu server.

> In Linux and Solaris guests, VirtualBox graphics and mouse integration goes through the X Window System. <sup>[Virtual Box User Manual](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch04.html)</sup>

The only benefit from guest additions is that you are able to access Virtual Box Shared Folders. This however can (and to my opinion should) also be done with networking, independent of guest additions.

Comment: Is there not a way to configure the numbers of rows and columns used in the server's console session? I don't need to resize the window as such, but rather to have more rows and columns of text visible. Some g++ messages are lengthy and hard to read with only 80 columns.

Comment: For others searching similar problems, I'd also mention that if you're running an Ubuntu Desktop with vintage 14.04 or later as a guest, the VMWare provided Guest Additions didn't work properly with the kernel and drivers until they were updated around Aug of 2017.  Using the latest versions now works.